# How to get compiler to deduce parameters for function with `concept auto...` given initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to get the hang of C++20 concepts. I want to define a function taking an arbitrary number of `Foo` instances and have the compiler implicitly convert input arguments to Foo instances. The problem is that the implicit conversion does not seem to work if I use `initializer_list`s. The last line in the following code is the offending one.

Is this possible with concepts and C++20? If yes, how should I change my code? If no, is there any other way to let the compiler to automatically do the implicit conversion?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

struct Foo {
    Foo(){ std::cout << "No argument!\n"; }
    Foo(int){ std::cout << "One argument!\n"; }
    Foo(int, int){ std::cout << "Two arguments!\n"; }
};

// function takes a single Foo
void foo(Foo foo){}

// function takes any number of Foos
template <typename... Foos>
requires (std::is_convertible_v<Foos, Foo> && ...)
void foos(Foos... foos){}
 
int main()
{
    // converting ctors work
    Foo x = 42;
    Foo y = {42, 42};
    Foo z = {};

    std::cout << "\n";

    // argument deduction works for foo
    foo(42);
    foo({42, 42});
    foo({});

    std::cout << "\n";

    // argument deduction works for foos using only second ctor
    foos(1, 2, 3);

    std::cout << "\n";

    // argument deduction does not work for foos if we use initializer lists
    foos(42, {42, 42}, {});
}
```

GCC complains:

```
 error: too many arguments to function 'void foos(Foos ...) [with Foos = {}]'
```

MSVC complains:

```
'initializer list': is not a valid template argument for 'Foos'
```

Clang complains:

```
candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced incomplete pack <int, (no value), (no value)> for template parameter 'Foos'
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/rz6c3odYK)

Comment: `{..}` has no types, and can only be deduced as `std::ininitilizer_list<T>` or `T[N]`.

Comment: braced initializer list (not to be confused with std::initializer_list) do not have a type.  There is nothing to be deduced

Comment: Ok, but I since the braced initializer list is converted (is this even a conversion?) to a Foo in `foo({42})`, I was hoping that it works for the varidatic version of the function as well. Is there any way to achieve this? How do I define a variadic function accepting only `Foo`s that behaves like the non-variadic function accepting a single `Foo`?

Comment: @joergbrech Templates don't do conversions.  They are given objects that have types, they deduces those types, and the proceed if everything checks out.  If you give it an object that does not have a type, then the whole process just stops.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOlvier. I was always bothered by having to write `template <typename... Args> void foo(Args&... args){}` when I knew exactly that each type in `Args` is going to have to be convertible to `Foo`. I was hoping that with C++20 I could constrain the parameter pack so far that the function actually *is* a function accepting only `Foo&`s and behaves like the non-variadic one. But it seems like concepts don't do that for me.

Comment: For some context: I want to get rid of explicitly having to write out `Slice` in lines 123-124 in https://godbolt.org/z/Kc9hdM8ra for cosmetic purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{..}` has no types, and can only be deduced as `std::ininitilizer_list<T>` or `T[N]`.

As alternative, you might use

```
void foos(std::initializer_list<Foo> foos){/**/}
```

with call similar to:

```
foos({42, {42, 42}, {}});
```

Comment: Ok, the additional braces bother me a little bit. But this is the obvious solution. Thanks!